# Why can courts refuse evidence?

Tags: criminal-law, evidence, rules-of-court, admissibility

##### The question

Layman here. This question was inspired by [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/84088/ordered-to-unlocking-a-car-trunk-may-i-lawfully-refuse) and random things I've heard/read over the years.

I'm quite confused by a concept that comes up again and again and which people seem to hold for self-evident. And that concept is that there is some evidence which a court will refuse to admit. And that confuses be because... well, there's evidence. It leads to the truth. Why aren't you taking it?!

It's very easy to come up with realistic examples where:

- There is a piece of evidence which is clearly and irrefutably shows that a person did something very bad (say, murder)
- This evidence is for whatever reason "not admissible" (say, it was obtained illegally)
- And there is no other piece of evidence that would incriminate this person.

Does that mean that the perpetrator gets to go free? How can the court refuse to admit evidence, especially if it's the only useful evidence existing? And if yes, then why is this so and where is this practice useful?

---

##### Some examples from the top of my head

The example question above deals with unlawful searches. Imagine that a police officer decided to search a car (or an apartment) and forcefully did so against the protests of the owner (or maybe the owner wasn't even present). They thought they might find drugs or something, but instead they are surprised to discover a dead body, clearly murdered. So... now what? According to the above question, since the search was illegal, this is inadmissible evidence in the court. Does that mean that the owner of the car/apartment gets to go away scott-free? Do they launch a new investigation and try to find other evidence *except* the fact that it was inside the property of this guy here (and failing to do that, release them)? If the owner of the car/apartment says "I don't know what you're talking about, I last saw Jimmy here alive and well at the pub last night; I never seen his corpse before." - can they call him out on the obvious lie?

Or, another example. I don't know about USA, but here in Europe it's illegal to record someone's phone calls without a warrant (or something like that; it's serious). Any recordings obtained unlawfully will be inadmissible as evidence.

Let's now imagine that I've gone the full extra mile and have secretly bugged everything in my neighbour's house because I suspect (but have no evidence) that they murdered my child last month. I've got hidden cameras, microphones everywhere, etc. So one day I catch him talking to his spouse on the phone and mentioning the murder, admitting to doing it, and even telling where he buried the body.

Now I have evidence... or do I? I give the recording to the police, they search the indicated place and they do find the body, but since they cannot accept my recording as evidence... does that mean that my neighbour now has no consequences? Let's also suppose that no other evidence is found that would indicate his guilt (the guy was thorough). Obviously I'd get some grief for bugging my neighbour's house, but do I now also become the prime suspect in the murder of my own child? After all - the recording of my neighbour's confession "officially doesn't exist", and I'm the one who told the police where to dig, so...

Comment: Please add a jurisdiction as the answer can change dramatically without it.

Comment: @hszmv - I don't have one in mind, this seems to be a very common theme in all jurisdictions that I've heard of. OK, maybe in something like Sharia law (which is based on religious texts) this is different, I don't know. Can I say "any jurisdiction where this is a thing"?

Comment: By the way, not all jurisdictions let courts refuse evidence. In Sweden *fri bevisprövning* (something like "free examination of evidence") applies: you can present any evidence you can get your hands on, but the court may not give it any particular value.

Comment: Seems interesting and I'm not sure the answers are really getting to it. So.... if you murder someone... all you really need is your old buddy, who is a local cop, to show up and illegally search and "find" the body, thereby rendering the evidence inadmissible? Legally they can't even say there's been a murder because the evidence (your knife, your gun, your car, your trunk, the corpse) is all inadmissible? Suddenly I want to write a crime novel.

Comment: @JamieB, ...doctrine of inevitable discovery applies there: if a legitimate investigation would have eventually gotten there via some means that _doesn't_ involve cheating, evidence can find its way back in.

Comment: @JamieB you can submit a stand-alone question

Comment: "That it is better 100 guilty Persons should escape than that one innocent Person should suffer, is a Maxim that has been long and generally approved." - Benjamin Franklin

Comment: It's a maxim that I too approve, although one does need to take it with a grain of salt, because in it's pure form it directly follows that it would be best to just discard all laws and law enforcement. But what I don't see is how discarding evidence helps in getting closer to this ideal. (Let us also remember, that some evidence can be useful for _defence_ of an innocent person)

Comment: This is much more prevalent in the US than in other parts of the world.... and the answers you have gotten so far are quite US-centric. Just saying, take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: Police officer might be punished for illegal search, but will his boss (and the boss of his boss etc) also face any consequences? Also, your "bug neighbor's house" scenario smells of vigilantism and there is a fairly short step to "I hate neighbors so I will bug their house, hopefully they will admit to something bad and I get them behind bars". That said, most countries also consider what was found.

Comment: @ZizyArcher - I would expect all these cases to be dealt with in the law.

Comment: @Vilx- "because in it's pure form it directly follows that it would be best to just discard all laws and law enforcement." Not really.  The phrase didn't just pick 100 at random, it's specifically thinking about the trade-off between type 1 and type 2 errors and states that  100 to 1 is an the acceptable compromise between the two. The phrase isn't making a general statement about how there should never be guilty people sentenced, it explicitly admits this is an inevitably and attempts to reach a balancing point of how possible that should be

Comment: @eps - I kinda didn't take the number "100" literally, especially as the quote is often used with different numbers - see, for example, one of the answers right here. The way I perceive it is "Better multiple guilty people are unpunished than a single innocent person is punished". The conclusion of abolishing all laws comes when you want to _absolutely minimize_ the number of innocently punished people. Only without laws will there ever be no innocent people punished. But where exactly to draw the line - that I suspect is one of those eternal debates.

Comment: Regarding the law, there is no such thing as “over here in Europe”, every country is different. And one has to be careful to not incorrectly assume that local law as like that in US movies :) For example of n Germany, evidence which has been obtained unlawfully is not necessarily inadmissible.

Comment: @CarstenS Yes, I was surprised to learn that it is not always the case.

Comment: Your example (a murder with only one piece of evidence) is likely the extreme, but the idea is that the risk of the police being allowed to violate the rights of everyone is considered to be worse than the risk of a criminal going free.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Different exclusionary rules have different reasons.

Hearsay is frequently inadmissible because it's less reliable for the court to hear Alice saying "Bob told me that Carol hit him" than to hear Bob saying "Carol hit me."  Another even more critical problem with hearsay testimony is that the defense cannot cross examine the person who made the statement in court.  If Bob is there, the defense can ask questions such as "where did Carol hit you" and "did Carol use her right or left hand" to clarify the testimony or call its veracity into question.  Alice, not having been a direct witness to the act, will not be able to respond to many of these questions.

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Evidence obtained in violation of a constitutional right is inadmissible because admitting it amounts to allowing police or prosecutors to violate people's constitutional rights in order to obtain convictions.  Not only does an unconstitutional search itself violate the rights of the person being searched, but so does the use of evidence acquired in such a search.  See [Fruit of the poisonous tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_of_the_poisonous_tree) at Wikipedia and the cases linked therein, especially [Silverthorne Lumber Co. v. United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverthorne_Lumber_Co._v._United_States) and [Nardone v. United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nardone_v._United_States).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139056/discussion-on-answer-by-phoog-why-can-courts-refuse-evidence).

Comment: Would you consider adding the following:

> _Privileges_ are another reason that relevant information is excluded from court. The common law and legislatures have recognized that certain relationships require such a high guarantee of privacy that information exchanged in those relationships should not be compellable before a court. Examples are solicitor-client privilege, executive privilege, spousal privilege, and journalist-source privilege (a non-absolute statutory privilege in the Canada Evidence Act).

Comment: Another issue with hearsay is that it doesn't come with the penalty of perjury. If Bob says to Alice "Carol hit me", and Carol did not in fact hit him, he can't be charged with perjury, because he didn't make the claim under oath, and Alice can't be charged with perjury, since her claim that Bob made the claim was in fact true.

Answer (score 26):

You need to ask *why* evidence gets excluded. For example evidence that was obtained by a search without a proper warrant. That's not excluded to protect criminals, it's excluded so that law abiding citizens are protected from having their home or their car or their body searched by a police officer. So first we have a law: A police officer is not allowed to search your home without a search warrant.

But what if they do? As a society, we want to prevent it from happening, and you prevent it by having punishment. However, if you punish police officers directly, you have the problem that a police officer is with one foot in jail all the time, so nobody wants to be a police officer. If we had a law that they get punished if they search your home and nothing against you is found, that would give a police officer very good reason to fabricate evidence to find. So the punishment is something that (a) any police officer dislikes and (b) that makes searching your home without a warrant pointless: And disallowing any evidence from such a search is something that any police officer dislikes, and makes them look for legal ways to find the evidence.

Comments: "Trusting that the existing American systems for disciplining officers could reliably deter officers from violating citizens' right is also somewhat optimistic". Any search without warrant would end up in court, in front of a judge. Who would ask for the search warrant, there wouldn't be one, so the search was without warrant, so the police officer is in trouble. Now if you think police officers would come and search my home just to have an excuse to mess it up, that's outside this question.

Vilx: phoog explained the law. I tried to explain why the law is there and in that form and not another form.

All in all, it is a very simple rule (simple rules are easy to follow), it protects innocent people from searches without search warrant (because police officers would have zero motivation to perform such a search), and it doesn't protect people committing crimes *much* (because when a person has committed a crime, hopefully the police would be able to get a search warrant, while for a person not committing any crime this would be less likely).

Comment: I _am_ asking why evidence gets excluded. It's literally there, in my question: `And if yes, then why is this so and where is this practice useful?` Anyways, I'm not sure I follow this part: `However, if you punish police officers directly, you have the problem that a police officer is with one foot in jail all the time`. Why so? If they search someone with a warrant, they are in the clear.

Comment: Trusting that the existing American systems for disciplining officers could reliably deter officers from violating citizens' right is also somewhat optimistic.

Comment: @Vilx-, I think the sentence "You need to ask why evidence gets excluded" was a lead-in to an answer to the question of why it gets excluded.  (I agree with you that it wasn't a very clear lead-in.)  Anyway, the point of the answer seems to be that you exclude evidence because it's a way to motivate law enforcement officers to only conduct legal searches and seizures without a direct punishment to the LEOs (which could either dissuade people from becoming LEOs or encourage bad behavior by LEOs, depending on the nature of the punishment).

Comment: The line `However, if you punish police officers directly, you have the problem that a police officer is with one foot in jail all the time` is suggesting that if you punish officers directly for conducting an illegal search and seizure, it becomes in an officer's best interest to conduct **no** searches or seizures (and possibly avoid the profession entirely) rather than risk punishment for mistakenly believing a search is lawful.  If they're insulated from _direct_ consequences but risk their evidence being thrown out, they can safely conduct whatever they believe to be a legal search.

Comment: @KrystenDevro - I understand the argument, but it seems to me to be on shaky ground. Officers are already doing a lot of things that would be crimes for anyone else to do, and would be a crime for them to do without proper preconditions. Searches are one thing, but what about weapon use? When the time comes to do it, the decision will most likely have to be made in a split second. Do you protect them from the consequences of an unnecessary shooting? That invites them to shoot first and ask questions later. Do you punish them for it? That then discourages from using weapons when needed. Etc.

Comment: @KrystenDevro - I think the bottom line is - there are a ton of similar conditions in a policeman's line of work. They have to know their rights and responsibilities - that's part of their job. If there is suspicion of misconduct, then an investigation is launched. I don't see why evidence gathering should be any different. But I can also totally see it being the reason for the existence of this law (discarding of illegally obtained evidence).

Comment: @Vilx- A lot of what you just said is the idea behind [qualified immunity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualified_immunity); and the shooting scenarios you gave are an example of what's driving some jurisdictions to question whether LEOs should have qualified immunity.  One thing that occurs to me is that there's a chain of people involved here; having illegal evidence be inadmissible frees you from figuring out who to punish (as opposed to having a LEO say their superior verbally ordered them to do it, etc) since it's in all of law enforcement's best interest that evidence be admissible.

Comment: @Vilx- the point is, if you don't discard the evidence, you give police a huge incentive to just break open every door, stop every car, search every person, all in the hopes of finding *something* incriminating. That means living in a police state, which most people don't like.

Comment: @JordiVermeulen - I'm sorry, I don't follow. How is that a huge incentive? What do they gain from that? It's not as if their monthly bonus depends on the number of searches performed. And going on a spree of unlawful searches should (in theory) result in a huge number of complaints, investigations, lawsuits, and an unpleasant aftermath. Just because the evidence suddenly starts to matter doesn't mean they won't get punished for breaking the law.

Comment: @Vilx- their job is to get criminals in jail. Randomly searching peoples' homes helps you find more criminals, because some of those people are criminals.

Comment: @Vilx- real police officers and departments are very much evaluated based on the number of fines, arrests and convictions they achieve.

Comment: @JordiVermeulen - Ahh! Now that's the missing piece of the puzzle!

Comment: I think casting the exclusion of evidence as punishing officers is inappropriate.  They may well be punished by their superiors, as a result of the evidence being excluded, but I think the reason for the exclusion itself is best cast in the terms of the most recent comments preceding this: to avoid providing an incentive for officers to violate citizens' rights.  Overall, however, yes, this is a "protect everybody" matter, not an attempt to shield criminals specifically.

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR: The law against torture and unwarranted searches have the same base justification: to protect the guilty.  Why protect the guilty? Because if the law doesn’t protect the guilty, it won’t protect the innocent. As proven  by the fact that something other than the law was used to **determine** they were guilty.

Long version: Some “evidence” isn’t actually evidence.  Hearsay is the prime example of that, and it is excluded because while it appears to be evidence it’s actually not.  If Sally tells Jenny that she robbed the 7-11 the day before, that doesn’t even prove that Sally was in the same time zone as the 7-11 at that time, let alone that she actually robbed it.

Another example is confession under torture, is that evidence?  The accused was burned until he said what he was told to say, that may or may not have lead to other physical evidence, but can you trust that evidence? Is it evidence against the accused, or evidence against the person that burned him until he said what they wanted him to say?  Or was there someone else involved that told the torturer what to get the accused to say?

But you are probably thinking of the simple case of searching without a warrant, surely that is safe? Searching without a warrant is a crime, with multiple offenders, it is also a conspiracy to commit the crime. You want to trust the word of people who committed a crime and engaged in a conspiracy to commit a crime against a person to present evidence they supposedly found confirming the guilt of the person they are conspiring against?

So why not make it legal, then there’s no problem right? It’s not a crime, there is no conspiracy, everything is good, right? Except historically those in power have been quite willing to order their minions to make up evidence against those they deemed enemies, as well as having them tortured into confirming that the evidence was true.  Even if we suppose we have a better class of bad Powers That Be nowadays, that wouldn’t be willing to torture people, expecting them to not make up evidence against people that they HONESTLY (but carelessly) believe are guilty is most certainly factually wrong, proven by various court cases where they did just that to convict people they thought were guilty.

Throwing out illegally obtained evidence is the least we can do, because it’s generally not practical to punish the criminal’s who illegally obtained evidence as they deserve.  Why isn’t it practical? Because frequently it takes a law degree and several hours of study to come to the correct conclusion, and the cops don’t have that kind of time.  Also, it’s hard to tell the difference between didn’t care and didn’t know.  The appropriate punishment would be the same as the accused would face if convicted of the crime, and if you make it a capital offense to get it wrong, it’ll be a lot easier and safer for the cops to shoot someone they think is guilty in “self defense” than to try to collect the evidence.

Comment: And my answer is exactly the opposite: The laws are there to protect the innocent.

Comment: @gnasher729: if they are there to protect the innocent, then it’s ok to ignore them when dealing with the guilty. And everyone is guilty once the red hot pincers come out.

Comment: No, @jmoreno, regardless of the purpose of the laws, it is not ok to ignore them under any circumstances.  Moreover, in the U.S. everyone must be presumed innocent until proven guilty, and they can be proven guilty only by a court of law, no matter how much evidence is discovered or by what means.  We protect the innocent because the innocent should be protected.  We accept that protecting the guilty, too, is among the costs of adequately doing that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger:a cost is something that should be reduced or eliminated, if protecting the guilty is a cost, then not protecting the guilty eliminates that cost.If the only reason not to torture someone is because they might be innocent, then rest assured, they’ll never get it wrong. If on the other hand torturing is bad, then we never get to a point where it’s Ok or even good.If the reason why the government is forbidden from going through someones private papers is because they might be innocent, then once again put your mind at rest, they don’t want to go through the papers of the innocent.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: while I say “guilty”, what that really means is regardless of guilt, it wouldn’t make sense to search people for evidence you are sure they don’t have. As for proven guilty in court, it wouldn’t even make it that far if everyone was convinced of the innocent of the accused.

Comment: Everything has a cost.  That's not something arbitrarily to be reduced or eliminated.  It's something to be *taken into account* when choosing action or policy.  If we choose not to accept protecting the guilty, then we do not get the benefit of protecting the innocent.  And I am of course speaking in terms of *actual* guilt or innocence in this regard, as a moral question, which is certainly the correct framework for understanding how we arrived where we now are.  You seem to be using the terms differently.

Comment: And the innocent *do* need protection -- not particularly those whom authorities are sure are innocent, but rather those who are innocent despite being suspected, and those who are innocent but happen to catch the attention of an authority, and those who aren't especially suspected but happen to be in the wrong place at the wrong time.  And that assuming only pure motives on the part of the government.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  I will add:  those who are (according to fallible, flawed humans, some of whom are hired as police officers) of the 'wrong' skin color, genotype, culture, religious beliefs or lack thereof; wear the 'wrong' clothing, 'wrong' hair length / color / style, ...

Comment: "If Sally tells Jenny that she robbed the 7-11 the day before" -- but because that's an admission of a crime, couldn't it fall under the "declaration against interest" exception to hearsay?

Comment: @nanoman: Sally was about to get a beat down for being a wimp, claiming to be an armed robbery was thus in her best interest.  Unfortunately the people she was bragging to are going to find out where she actually was, and she will be beat to death before she can go on trial.  Ah, well.  It's OK, she said she was guilty, no need to investigate any further.  No need to protect the guilty

Comment: No one is saying that Sally shouldn't get a fair trial or deserves to be killed with impunity. If Sally is murdered, that is a separate crime that should be prosecuted regardless of Sally's guilt. Otherwise, if the confession is introduced at Sally's trial, Sally can introduce rebuttal evidence to show why she lied. You don't seem to be engaging with the point that there *are* established exceptions to the hearsay rule. *Most* hearsay is inadmissible for the good reasons you note ("while it appears to be evidence it’s actually not"), but you chose an example that is not so clear.

Comment: @nanoman: I think the Q is about why, not what laws allow this, my answer and comments are addressing the why.   I wasn’t talking about admissible evidence, but rather direct evidence in a more abstract frame.  Even if it was on video and unquestionably admissible, it would be “here is the evidence that proves she said that” not “here is the evidence that proves she was there and participated in the robbery”.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that generally, evidence obtained without due process is **inherently unreliable**. For your first example, to legally get a warrant in many countries, you need to have to present a convincing argument that a crime was committed. In the case of searches, not needing to do so could easily allow for the planting of evidence on pretty much anyone. How could you know that the police officer hadn't knocked over a cyclist, thrown their body in the boot of the nearest person's car and "just happened upon it" later because they decided that the person might have drugs?

Unlike the example you give about police with guns making split second decisions, a search is a planned and coordinated act usually involving multiple people and other people not necessarily present may also be responsible for these actions (like a superior officer). As mentioned in another answer, to make sure justice is being served, it's also a better deterrent to enact a penalty that affects all parties and not just an individual or group of individuals.

With *any* evidence presented to a court, there has to be a level of trust that this evidence is legitimate. Obtaining it illegally undermines that trust because once someone has proven willing to break the rules to obtain it, how can you trust that they haven't broken the rules and invented it or tampered with it?

Your latter example is interesting because the difference here is that this evidence is submitted by a civilian. Depending on the circumstances, region and if there are checks you can make on the evidence's validity, it could still be deemed admissable. After all, if I were to rob a house and witness a murder, many countries would still allow me to take to the stand and give testimony (which *is* evidence). Me having committed a crime to see this doesn't change that. In the case of law enforcement recording people, the people retrieving and verifying its validity are the same, an obvious conflict of interest.

Either way, evidence not being admissable in a court of law wouldn't make you a suspect, it just means the police would have to find other evidence, and the location of a body might help provide enough so it would still be useful information for them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This seems to be the first answer that addresses the examples in the question. +1

Answer (score 3):

[common-law](/questions/tagged/common-law)

> that confuses be because... well, there's evidence. It leads to the truth. Why aren't you taking it?!

Firstly, because whether a piece of evidence actually leads to "the truth" is usually arguable. The parties will normally have different views on whether it does.

For example, someone saying something about what they saw/heard *is* evidence. But is the person to be believed? Are they available to repeat the evidence from the witness stand, or are only their *words* available (as heard/recorded by someone)?

And then, very importantly, the courts do not actually seek "the truth". It's a common misconception that they do. Instead, they resolve the *dispute* between the parties.

So, rules have been worked out over the centuries as to how disputes are to be resolved. These include rules of evidence.

Comment: What is truth is a philosical concept with thousands of years of critical thought behind it and no real widespread consensus.

Comment: The courts can only ask the allowed evidence be put trough the reasonable doubt standard and hope that the truth will be served.

Comment: OK, but how does this all lead to "this is a piece of evidence that we will not accept because it was obtained illegally"? What is the reasoning behind this? Note that I don't question the veracity of the evidence. I can totally understand not accepting unreliable evidence. I'm talking about the cases where the evidence can be verified to be true, and yet still rejected.

Comment: @Vilx- It doesn't. You effectively ask a few different questions, and I've only addressed the base one at high level. Also, say in New Zealand, illegally obtained evidence may sometimes be admissible.

Comment: @Vilx-: Courts have no direct power to punish cops who act illegally, and police departments often turn a blind eye to cops that act unlawfully in ways that help prosecutors win cases.  By contrast, unlawful actions by cops which cause evidence to be thrown out, thus resulting in prosecutors losing cases, are far less likely to be tolerated.  While the exclusionary rule isn't a perfect deterrent against unlawful actions by cops, it seems to be much more effective than any other alternative.

Comment: @supercat - `Courts have no direct power to punish cops who act illegally` wait, what? I though that they had to obey the law just like everyone else, and could be sued just like everyone else. Sure, their job gives them extra privileges, but only under certain conditions. I understand that other police officers are likely to turn a blind eye towards the transgressions of their colleagues - but if someone complains or sues, that should still work just the same, no?

Comment: @Vilx-, look up "qualified immunity". As implemented in practice, it provides police officers an extremely broad defense (considerably broader than theory might imply on account of second-order effects: an officer isn't considered personally liable unless they should have known violating someone's rights were illegal, and courts find that it would be illegal if there were a record of successful prosecutions, but because officers violating civilians' rights always get away with it on account of there not being precedent there often _are_ no prior successful prosecutions to meet that standard).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy just a nitpick: qualified immunity applies in the context of civil claims made against the officers by the rights holder. So rather than there needing to be a "successful prosecution" it should say "successful claims against officers on a nearly identical basis." There is also acknowledgment that some violations are so flagrant and obvious that there is no need for prior precedent squarely on point (Hope v. Pelzer (2002)).

Comment: "The truth?  You can't handle the truth!"

Answer (score 2):

> Does that mean that the perpetrator gets to go free?

Quite possibly, depending on the case.

> Why is this so and where is this practice useful?

At some point it was decided that it's better to let some guilty people go free than to allow violations of constitutional rights in order to get convictions.

Comment: Mind you, the person doing the violation would also know full well that they would get punished for their transgression to the full extent of the law. Shouldn't that be enough to stop them?

Comment: @Vilx- looking at the amount of inadmissible evidence that gets excluded on that basis, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

How can a court refuse evidence? Because there are clear rules as to how evidence can be obtained and how they can be entered into a trial.

It is worth noting that concept of justice is not just who did the crime must do the time. Justice for the victim is just as important as justice for the accused.

If police obtain evidence illegaly then it is for the sake of justice that, that evidence is excluded.

If that means an otherwise slam-dunk case gets thrown out then that is inline with justice being served not against.

Poor policing is not the accused problem. Nor should the system allow police to do whatever they like.

The blackstone ratio, being a cornerstone of legal thought in much of the west says... "It is better that 10 guilty people go free than 1 innocent person suffer."

Our justice system is skewed to bring forth not guilty verdicts. As unpleasant as that view may be to victims of crimes. As disgusting it is when terrible crimes are not punished in a way that alleviates our need for revenge.

It is the system we have and a concept you will only truly appreciate when you get accused of a crime.

Comment: OK, but how does this all lead to "this is a piece of evidence that we will not accept because it was obtained illegally"? What is the reasoning behind this? How does this help not to falsely convict people?

Comment: Read this. To put it simply the concept of guilt out of a legal pov is different than the collequil sense. Before I got myself legally educated on this site I thought the same way - https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/62104/in-the-us-are-jurors-actually-judging-guilt

Comment: I read that link, but I still do not grasp the difference or how it applies here. Yes, people are not perfect and evidence is not perfect and wrong judgments do happen (guilty people are found not guilty and vice versa). And i also understand that the system is skewed towards not falsely finding one guilty. That is all fine. But how is dismissing some evidence (even if it can be demonstrated to be true beyond reasonable doubt) supposed to lead to less false convictions?

Answer (score 1):

> How can the court refuse to admit evidence, especially if it's the only useful evidence existing?  And if yes, then why is this so and where is this practice useful?

The rules of evidence define what is and isn't legally evidence, and what is and isn't admissible. These rules vary by jurisdiction, and may differ in civil and criminal law. As underlined by phoog in [their answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/84102/25215), you don't want to reward investigators who act above the law and violate your rights, and you don't want to give evidence credibility it has not earned.

Consider that in a jury trial, like criminal trials in the United States, the worst thing that can happen is that someone is wrongfully convicted because a jury was presented shaky evidence that influenced their judgement, even if they were told to ignore it. The second worst thing may be that the trial has to be redone because the jury's judgement was tainted by the evidence, making everybody lose precious time and money.

Conversely, in a trial by a professional judge, the judge knows the law and is better equipped to evaluate a piece of evidence. The risk of their judgment being influenced by wrongful evidence may be considered negligible since by definition a professional judge is trusted with their judgement and their ability to tell right from wrong, in a way individual jurors simply aren't.

This might explain why rules of evidence are much more stringent in the United States than in France, where illegally obtained evidence may be admitted. But even if admitted, you still have to show that the evidence is genuine, not tampered with, and actually shows the thing you say it shows, or else it has little value.

> I give the recording to the police, they search the indicated place and they do find the body, but since they cannot accept my recording as evidence... does that mean that my neighbour now has no consequences?

The rules of evidence need not apply to a police investigation. If we presume your recording is inadmissible, it means it can't be brought to court. But the police isn't the judiciary (it is, in fact, the executive), and an investigation isn't a prosecution or defence.

Rules may vary, but generally inadmissible evidence can still be used in the course of an investigation. Suppose a police officer overheard someone talk about your neighbour and how they heard from someone that they buried a body in the forest. That would be woefully inadmissible evidence by itself (two words: objection, hearsay). However, it may give cause to the officer to grab a shovel and start digging.

If the police finds a body on the basis of your illegal recording, then they still find a body. The recording is essentially an anonymous tip, it can't be used in court, but the body you find thanks to it can be used, and you and your neighbour can definitely become a prime suspects in a homicide investigation.

In the unlikely event the investigation can't turn up any useful and admissible evidence and exhausts all possible avenues, then it would most likely be shelved until such time new evidence turns up. Without useable evidence, prosecution can't show guilt beyond a reasonable doubt, so there's no point in going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Your question invokes fairness of outcomes, i.e. you perceive the system as more fair if it is more accurate in determining guilt versus innocence. In other words, [distributive justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_justice).

Another concept is fairness of process or [procedural justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_justice), i.e. the system is fair if everybody has to play by the same rules. If obtaining a wiretap was illegal, then we should not allow any recording into the courtroom, whether the recording was made or not. We should enforce that the "no wiretap" rule is followed to keep the playing field level, even if someone did make a recording.

Similarly, it can be argued that people don't have "due process" or "equal protection under the law" if the prosecution gets to break the rules of the legal system against some defendants and not others.

Under procedural fairness, I think there is also less of an assumption of an objective truth about guilt versus innocence. If you instead think about guilt or innocence as simply an outcome of a two-sided contest, you may see the importance that the contest have fair and consistent rules for all participants.

Comment: It's kind of weird to think of a lawsuit as a contest. This implies that whoever has the best lawyers will win. And hint: better lawyers are usually also more expensive, so the contest often becomes about who has deeper pockets and can afford better lawyers. Which... kinda feels like of the opposite of what law should be (fair and impartial to everyone)? Even though there are plenty of real-world examples of exactly this happening, I don't really think this is a "feature" of the system, but more like a glaring fault.

Comment: @Vilx- it would more be the best combination of lawyer and actual evidence that wins. The best chess player can't win without pieces. One would hope that lawyer's ability matters less than the evidence, but I generally agree about the real-world pitfalls.

Comment: Of course, the same kinds of concerns can apply in distributive justice. In your question, if we admit illegal evidence, rich people are more able to break the rules (e.g. hire someone to make an illegal search that turns up evidence) or protect themselves from broken rules (e.g. use methods to avoid illegal wiretaps), so if we don't exclude illegally-obtained evidence, again depth of pockets comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

There are already plenty of other answers which address matters like why evidence might get thrown out, but I would like to point out that evidence that gets thrown out can still influence a trial. I raise this point because you exemplified a scenario wherein your child is murdered by a neighbor.

Specifically, witnesses cannot provide testimony that would contradict physical evidence that was prevented from being heard at trial because that would be perjury. For example, suppose a police officer conducted an unwarranted search of a drug dealer's car and found a kilogram of cocaine. Because the cocaine was found from a warrantless search, it will be excluded from trial.

If, for some reason, the prosecutor wants to proceed to trial they will do so without being able to present the kilogram of cocaine. But by the same note, the defense will not be able to put forth a witness who testifies that there were no drugs in the car at all at the time of the search because that would be perjury and an attorney who prompted a question to elicit that response could be guilty of suborning perjury.

Comment: But how could you prove that it was perjury, if you cannot bring the cocaine in?

Comment: @Vilx- the judge of the trial for the cocaine charge is aware of what evidence has and has not been admitted into evidence and the reasons for its exclusion. This would be handled in pre-trial motions which admit or exclude evidence. Testimony that is known to be perjury would need to be stricken from the record and could not be considered by the jury for the cocaine trial. Assuming a prosecutor wished to proceed on a charge of perjury, that would be a separate trial, and in that separate trial the kilo of cocaine's presence in the trunk could be admitted into evidence.

Comment: @Vilx- to clarify, evidence that is excluded from a trial for Defendant #1 because it was obtained in a manner that impugns Defendant #1's rights is evidence that doesn't exist for the purpose of that trial. However, that evidence may still be admissible in another wholly separate trial relating to Defendant #2. After all, the evidence in Defendant #2's trial wasn't obtained in fashion that denied Defendant #2 their rights.